# Eclipse Mars fails to install feature

Tags: eclipse-jdt, pde

I have the following odd problem:

I am working on a jdt feature. The ant script that generates the jars, signs them, etc, has worked like a charm for months.

I downloaded Mars, installed the feature successfully once(fully functional plugin). I had to make some changes, regenerated the jars and all hell broke loose.

Suddenly the icons were not in the path, tried to reinstall ide from scratch several times and now the feature fails to install silently.

After the signature verification dialogs, it silently fails. The plugins and features dirs have the installed components but the plugin doesn't load at all.

I deleted .eclipse and .p2 several times to no avail.

Clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OS X Mavericks, 1.7 71-b14 jvm

Comment: There is a socket timed out exception inside oomph but nothing else.

Comment: Is there another place with more verbose output? or flag that forces the feature install to be more verbose?

Comment: Well if I use the dropins dir ( which I have never used, I have always used the feature installer until 2 days ago) the pde picks up the plugin. Go figure.  But annoying

Comment: Regarding the icons: do you reference icons from JDT or are those your own? Note that JDT has replaced the old .gif icons by .png icons.

Comment: Regarding the failed install: anything in the **Error Log** view (or `yourworkspace/.metadata/.log`)? IIRC some errors are also logged into `eclipse/configuration`.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I erased everything from disk and moved the .app (I am using os x) to the applications folder before doing anything else again. It works like a champ again. I must have created a permissions mess